# How to refactor firebase query to a specific thenable function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, es6-promise

I have a function that returns a snapshot of a firebase firestore query. It is as follows:

```
export async function getClientWorkflowsFromFirebase(clientID) {

    const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection("workflows").where("client_id", "==", clientID).get();
    return snapshot


}
```

To run the above code and get the result I want I do this:

```
  getClientWorkflowsFromFirebase("some-client-id").then((x)=>{
      x.forEach(doc => {
          console.log(doc.data());
      });
  });
```

It works fine but it is not the API that I want. I want to get the same result without the end user having to remember `doc.data()` .

Instead I would like to have the *thenable* function give the user the data like this:

```
getClientWorkflowsFromFirebase("some-client-id").then((arr)=>{
      arr.forEach(val => {
          // data is then available in val, not val.data()
      });
  });
```

How do I rewrite the function to deliver that end result ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the QuerySnapshot's [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) array to convert the array of document snapshots into and array of JavaScript objects.

```
export async function getClientWorkflowsFromFirebase(clientID) {
    const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection("workflows").where("client_id", "==", clientID).get();
    return snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
}
```

Definitely learn to use `Array.map()` - it should be in every JavaScript programmer's toolbox.